# Is it possible to insert the two new contacts with same display name on Android 2.2?

Tags: android

I need to insert two new contacts with same display name. But all other fields are different.

How its possible?

I tried to insert like this, but both contacts are conflicted on Android 2.2 contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's 2.x Contacts API will aggregate 2 raw contacts with the same name by default. See the section **Automatic aggregation** in [Using the Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html).

What you need to do is disable automatic aggregration, which is also described in that very useful article. You merely have to set your RawContact record's AGGREGATION_MODE value to AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED.